# How to get the second half of a list of lists as a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, numpy, zip

So I know that to get a single column, I'd have to write

```
a = list(zip(*f)[0])
```

and the resulting a will be a list containing the first element in the lists in f.

How do I do this to get more than one element per list? I tried

```
a = list(zip(*f)[1:19])
```

But it just returned a list of lists where the inner list is the composed of the ith element in every list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easy way is not to use `zip()`.  Instead, use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
a = [sub[1:19] for sub in f]
```

If it is actually the second half that you are looking for:

```
a = [sub[len(sub) // 2:] for sub in f]
```

That will include the `3` in `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.  If you don't want to include it:

```
a = [sub[(len(sub) + 1) // 2:] for sub in f]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely prefer @zondo's solution for both performance and readability. However, a `zip` based solution is possible and would look as follows (in Python 2):

```
zip(*zip(*f)[1:19])
```

You should not consider this cycle of unpacking, zipping, slicing, unpacking and re-zipping in any serious code though ;)

In Python 3, you would have to cast both `zip` results to `list`, making this even less sexy.